# Django - haystack - jinja2, multivaluefield tags

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am using haystack with whoosh backend. I have django-taggit for tags in my model.

search_indexes.py:

```
class WorkIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    tags = indexes.MultiValueField()

    def prepare_tags(self, obj):
     return [tag.name for tag in obj.tags.all()] 

    def get_model(self):
        return Work

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

work_text.txt:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.description }}
{% for tag in tags %} {{ tag }} {% endfor %}
```

But when i search a work via tag i can not see a result? I have to note that i am using jinja2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The right template will be:

work_text.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.description }}
{% for tag in object.tags.all() %}{{ tag.name }} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's `object.tags.all` not `object.tags.all()`.